# Increase font Leading inside the paragraph for single line

Tags: fontsize

Inside the paragraph I want to increase the leading of particular line when math or special character comes in between the line. Here I inserted math fraction. Please provide solution how to fix this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{arcs,amsmath}

\begin{document}

A passengers flies from one city and then on to another, with the total cost of the flight being $\$ 320$. The order in which the plane flew between the three cities was, A passengers flies $\dfrac{1}{2}$ from one city and then on to another, with the total cost of the flight being $\$ 320$. The order in which the plane flew between the three cities was

\end{document}
```

[image: font size problem]

Comment: It would be much better simply not to use `\dfrac` as `\frac` would use an inline fraction designed to fit in the baselineskip, `\dfrac` forces the display style used inline, which is always going to look bad. (however you can increase `\lineskip` from its default of 1pt. (but I would not)

Comment: Or use `\nicefrac` or `\unitfrac`  from the  `units` package.

Comment: Thanks Fran for your quick response. It has worked fine for me and I got it what I exactly want :)